# express.Router() and requires in Express.js

Tags: node.js, express, caching

I am trying to organize my project according to Express 4.x new [`express.Router()`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#router) method.

As [Express' documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#router) describes it,

> A router object is an isolated instance of middleware and routes. You
>   can think of it as a “mini-application,” capable only of performing
>   middleware and routing functions.

For the sake of better understanding, let's consider this project structure:

```
project/
  index.js
  routes/
    myRouter.js
    ...
  ...
```

And the files themselves:

*index.js*

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express(); 
const path = require('path');

const myModule = require('myModule');   

app.use('/myRouter', require('routes/myRouter'));

// some more code using myModule set of functions
```

*routes/myRouter.js*

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const router = express.Router();

const myModule = require('myModule'); 

router.get('/', function(req, res){
        // some more code using myModule set of functions 
      });

module.exports = router;
```

As you can see, both files need to use `myModule`'s functions, so AFAIK both files need to require `myModule`.

How does Express handle this situation?

As I see it, Express directly imports `myRouter`'s code into `index.js` via `module.exports`. If so, is the engine somehow pre-compiling it? And then aren't `myRouters' requires` redundant?

If not, how does it affect performance? Should I avoid routers for my kind of task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing would be that it is not being compiled, it's not es6. Second app.js imports the module and run that module for your route so imports in your myRouter.js is completely necessary. [This](https://blog.risingstack.com/node-js-at-scale-module-system-commonjs-require/) article would certainly help you understand modules. One more thing is that it does decrease your application performance. Express is used on node.js and node.js imports are optimised with V8 engine. So don't worry about performance.

Comment: Not completely independent because your core app.js runs your module and make it a complete web app. Your structure is a standard one followed by most of the people. Also don't worry about performance, module does not decrease the performance, although it will increase the code readability and modularization.

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt answer! Very interesting article. Could you please include segments of the article in your original answer in order to avoid dead links?

Comment: So the core app and the router modules are are two completely independent applications? Is such a project organization suitable performance-wise? Should I prefer another way to handle the structure?

Comment: @Kathandrax I will update the answer. Nice suggestion by the way

Answer (score 1):

> How does Express handle this situation?

Express doesn't, Node does. From the [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching)

> Modules are cached after the first time they are loaded. This means (among other things) that every call to require('foo') will get exactly the same object returned, if it would resolve to the same file.
>
> Multiple calls to require('foo') may not cause the module code to be executed multiple times. This is an important feature....

So taking your application into consideration, `myModule` is already cached by the time the router loads it as `app.js` would be required first; any performance impact would be negligible.

Comment: Thank you very much for your valuable addition. It would actually complete very well the original answer.